# Is there any way except using counter to enable time based alerts

Tags: shell

Suppose that `ps -ef | grep apache | wc -l` gives output `2` which means 2 process are running.

In my server connection fluctuates, so I want to send an alert when the output of `ps -ef| grep apache |wc -l` is zero more than 5 Minutes.

Comment: You have to learn about [monitoring software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_monitoring). Or implement it with simple cron script. There is no shell feature for that.

Comment: Doing that well is hard work!  There are major systems that handle that sort of monitoring (whether they're available in Open Source is a separate question).  You might need to look for time series.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for ways to automatically restart a process that exited. You are probably thinking of automatic restarts that is implemented via `/etc/inittab` on RHEL 5 and earlier, or `/etc/init/*` on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send an alert when the output of ps -ef| grep apache |wc -l is zero more than 5 Minutes.

First,`ps -ef| grep apache` can be unreliable because it may count `grep apache` as an apache process.  To avoid that, use `ps -ef | grep '[a]pache'`.  Better, try: `pgrep apache`.  Also, if we are looking for zero or not zero processes, we don't need `wc -l`.

*If your needs are simple*, then here is a simple bash script that checks every minute to see if an apache process is running.  If five successive tests show no such process, it sends an email to user@admin:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while sleep 1m
do
        if pgrep apache >/dev/null
        then
                count=0
        else
                ((count++))
        fi
        if [ "$count" -ge 5 ]
        then
                echo "Houston, we have a problem: $count" | mail admin@host
                count=0
        fi
done
```

Since this only checks every minute, it could miss some process that starts and stops in less than a minute.  You may need to adjust the timing.  As Jonathan Leffler commented, doing this well is hard work.  This script is only intended as a quick-and-simple solution.